# Default UITableViewCell height is to big for the text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an UITableView with a default cell where I just add a string:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!

    cell.textLabel?.text = tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

    return cell
}
```

My problem is that the cell is too big for just some normal text. Here is a screenshot, the cell has the blue background:

[image]

I didn't have this issue before, when my data source was an array on String's. The issue appeared after I changed from Strings to custom objects. Not sure if this is related.

How can I fix this ? I tried setting the row height to custom value, but it doesn't have any effect.

edit with table view code:

```
extension TasksViewController {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!

        cell.textLabel?.text = tasks[indexPath.row].name
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dummyTxt.textField.text = tasks[indexPath.row].name
        dummyTxt.becomeFirstResponder()
        dummyTxt.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (_, index) in
            self.tasks.remove(at: index.row)
        }

        return [delete]
    }
}
```

Comment: show the configuration of the tableView

Comment: Please provide the code how you measure the height.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ: you mean from storyboard ?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed: I don't do anything to height. I just use the default height

Comment: means your tableview datasource and delegate methods

Comment: updated with all table view code.

Comment: @Kobe if you are not doing any height configuration then use try google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this on `tableView`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Do NOT override `heightForRowAt` delegate method.

And then just make sure that the prototype cell that you registered as `"Cell"` has proper constraints that can be used to calculate its height. In your case make sure that both top and bottom anchors of the label are constrained to the top and bottom anchors of the cell.

Comment: ok, but I don't have any label added to the cell. I am using the default textLabel.

Comment: @Kobe ok so what happens when you set `tableView.rowHeight = 30`?

Comment: Nothing, I tried to set it from storyboards, and nothing changes. I also tried your code here and same issue.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I was confusing estimatedRow with rowHeight. Changing rowHeight works.

Comment: @Kobe it's solved for you.. but sooner or later you will have to make the cells to adapt their content, so then you can come back to these answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Use following delegate method with returning some integer value, if you need same size for every cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

Hopes It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To set automatic dimension for row height & estimated row height, ensure following steps to make, auto dimension effective for cell/row height layout.

- Assign and implement tableview dataSource and delegate
- Assign `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight
- Implement delegate/dataSource methods (i.e. `heightForRowAt` and return a value `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to it)

-

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set dataSource and delegate for table
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    // Set automatic dimensions for row height
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}



// UITableViewAutomaticDimension calculates height of label contents/text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For label instance in UITableviewCell

- Set number of lines = 0 (& line break mode = truncate tail)

Comment: `table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is not a correct way to go, he should use a specific constant that best estimates the most common case..